# Python - Explicitly filling row 1 somehow fills row 0 in a 2D array

Tags: python

I am trying to write code for the Needleman-Wunsch sequence alignment algorithm, but I'm running into a bizarre issue. The way I learnt  it the first row (row 0) and the first column (column 0) is supposed to stay 0 throughout. However, my code seems to be filling the first row even if I'm explicitly updating the values in the score matrix from row 1 (second row) onwards. I'll attach the code here. Please note that it is incomplete and possibly very messily written with all the debug statements etc.

Thanks in advance!

```
def seq_align(s1, s2, scoring):
    '''s1, s2 - sequences to be aligned;
    scoring - scoring scheme of the form (match_score, mismatch_score, gap_penalty)'''
    m = len(s1) + 1 # number of rows of the score matrix
    n = len(s2) + 1 # number of columns of the score matrix

    score_matrix = [[0] * n]*m # initialising every element to 0

    print("Score matrix before filling")
    for i in range(len(score_matrix)):
        print("row #", i, " -->", score_matrix[i])
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            print("checking values of 0th row", score_matrix[0])
            print("Filling element: ", i, ",", j)
            s_ij = 0 # variable to store the score - match/mismatch
            if(s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]):
                s_ij = scoring[0]
            else:
                s_ij = scoring[1]
            t1 = score_matrix[i-1][j-1] + s_ij
            t2 = score_matrix[i-1][j] + scoring[2]
            t3 = score_matrix[i][j-1] + scoring[2]
            # print("t1, t2, t3 =", t1, t2, t3)
            score = max(t1, t2, t3)                       
            score_matrix[i][j] = score
            print("Filling element: ", i, ",", j, "with", score_matrix[i][j]) 
        print("After filling row #",i,"matrix-->")
        for idx in range(m):
            print(score_matrix[idx])

    
    print("First row -> ", score_matrix[0])
    
   return m + n # placeholder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = seq_align("ABC", "ABCDEF", (2, -1, -2))
```

Comment: What do you think `[[0] * n]*m` means?

Comment: Use `score_matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(m)]` instead.

Comment: If you look more closely, it actually fills *all* of the rows.

Comment: @ScottHunter doesn't it initialize all elements to 0?

Comment: It makes a list of `n` 0's, and then a list of *that* list `m` times; thus, every row is the *same list* (not just a *copy*).  That's why @Unmitigated's suggestion solves the problem: it makes each row independently.

Comment: @ScottHunter, okay, I understand that part better now, thanks. But the thing I don't understand is how the first row of my matrix has the values updated, even though I'm starting the for loops from the second row (index 1).

Comment: Because they are all *the same row*.